# truthy and falsy values for strings with explicit call

Tags: python

A non-empty string in Python should have a truthy value. Why is it that if I explicitly call the `__bool__()` function, I get an error? If I use an `if` statement, it seems to evaluate though.

```
>>> myvar = 'test'
>>> myvar.__bool__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__bool__'
>>> if myvar:
...     print("myvar TRUTHY")
...
myvar TRUTHY
>>>
```

Comment: The proper way to convert an object to `bool` is `bool(myvar)`, not `myvar.__bool__()`. Dunder methods are implementation details and should only be used when you really know what you're doing.

Comment: @MarkRansom is bool(myvar) the same thing as using myvar with an if statement? `if myvar: print("TRUTHY")`

Comment: I believe it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings don't have a `__bool__()` method (which is what the error is telling you). Instead, python will call `__len__()` on the string and return True if it's non-zero. As the python [data model mentions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__):

> When this method is not defined, `__len__()` is called, if it is
> defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero.
> If a class defines neither `__len__()` nor `__bool__()`, all its instances
> are considered true.

You can verify this by creating a subclass of `UserString` (or `str`) and noting when `__len__()` is called. It will get called when you use the string in a boolean context:

```
from collections import UserString

class myString(UserString):
    def __len__(self):
        print("length called")
        return super().__len__()
    
s = myString("hello")

if s:
    pass
# prints "length called"

bool(s)
# length called
# True
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), the truth value test depends on `__bool__` and `__len__` methods.  In case of strings, since `__bool__` method is undefined, the truth value of strings depends on `__len__` method, which is defined.